# Want to query a number of tables to see if data exists

Tags: sql, database, select

I have at least 4 tables.

I want to be able to use one table as the 'master' and query the next 3 tables to see if the value in the key field that exists within the master table exists in any of the other 3 tables.  I want to do this for all rows within the master table.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
Select Master.ID From Master Inner Join Detail1 on Master.ID = Detail1.ID
Union
Select Master.ID From Master Inner Join Detail2 on Master.ID = Detail2.ID
Union
Select Master.ID From Master Inner Join Detail3 on Master.ID = Detail3.ID
```

Might need to twiddle with the syntax as you didn't say which DBMS

Comment: Many thanks, let me give that a try.  I am fairly green with Oracle.  But you might have given me enough to start tinkering